# Can I use Eclipse-EMF's internal data structure?

Tags: uml, eclipse-emf

In EMF, a user can draw UML diagram and that UML model can be transformed into Java code. As far as I know EMF has its own internal data structure to capture the UML model user draws. And what I want to do is to make UML model by coding, not by drawing, i.e., by using EMF's internal data structure representing UML metamodel(Class, Package, Attribute, etc). Like,

```
UmlClass myClass = new UmlClass();
UmlAttribute myAttr = new UmlAttribute();
myClass.addAttribute(myAttr);
```

Is this possible(not even by EMF)? Anyway, I want to use a robust data structure that exactly reflects OMG's standard UML specification.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EMF is a modelling framework designed to support modelling in general, not just UML.

If it is UML in particular you're after, there is indeed such an implementation built on top of EMF. Check out [UML2](http://www.eclipse.org/modeling/mdt/?project=uml2).

Answer (score 0):

There are no classes exactly reflecting the OMG specification, but EMF ECore is a meta model for models. Therefore you can do what you want using EMF ECore. There is lots of doc at http://www.eclipse.org/modeling/emf/docs/#overviews and an excellent book. The link has a picture and link to the book.

An example:

```
EcoreFactory ecoreFactory = EcoreFactory.eINSTANCE;
EClass myClass = ecoreFactory.createEClass();
myClass.setName("MyClass");
EAttribute myAttr = ECoreFactory.createEAttribute();
myAttr.setName("myAttr");
myAttr.setEType(EcorePackage.Literals.ESTRING);
myClass.getEStructuralFeatures().add(myAttr);
```